# Cartopy: subsetting features for plotting a specific river

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartopy

Working in `Python3` with `cartopy`, I am trying to subset and plot a specific river from the Natureal Earth database.

It is quite straightforward to plot *all* the rivers and then set the extent over a particular area:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature

rivers = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='physical', name='rivers_lake_centerlines',
    scale='10m', facecolor='none', edgecolor='blue')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                         figsize=(10,6))
ax.add_feature(rivers, linewidth=1)
ax.set_extent([-65, -45, -40, -17.5])
plt.show()
```

(Results shown below)

However, if I wish to plot only a particular river (for purposes of illustration the Paraná, which is named `Paran?` in the data due to encoding issues, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this [The cartopy Feature interface documentation](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/feature_interface.html)

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `cartopy.io.shapereader`, here is the code that works on my computer:

```
from cartopy import config
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader

#config  # format-dict

# assuming you have downloaded that file already using your original code
# its full path name should be (Windows)
fpath = config['data_dir'] + r'\shapefiles\natural_earth\physical\10m_rivers_lake_centerlines.shp'

as_shp = shapereader.Reader( fpath )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1, \
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}, \
                       figsize=(10,6) )

# plot some geometries, based on their attribs
for rec in as_shp.records():
    if rec.attributes['name'] == 'Parana?ba':
        ax.add_geometries( [rec.geometry], ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='none', facecolor='blue' )
    pass

ax.coastlines( resolution='110m' )
ax.set_extent([-65, -45, -40, -17.5])
plt.show()
```

[image: the output]

Comment: any idea how to cause the rivers to be drawn as lines rather than as polygons?

Comment: stupid question -- fixed with `ax.add_geometries( [rec.geometry], ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='blue', facecolor='none')`